# Single SQL statement - is it possible?

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to work this out, in the past I would usually do this with multiple SQL statements and join the data with PHP. I'm aware that this is not the best way to program though so I'd like to try to get all my data with one SQL statement.

Here are the tables.

table pages:

```
id name fields
1 home 1,3,4
```

table data_fields:

```
id field
1 title
2 subtitle
3 description
4 image
```

table page_data:

```
id title subtitle description image link quote
1 Hello null descriptionText null null null
```

So basically I want to pull the page data depending on the page id.

How do I split up the `pages.fields` field that is separated with commas then get the fields required from `data_fields` and then pull the data from `page_data` depending on the field name retrieved from data_fields?

Comment: using the where clause in your query. show your query

Comment: Your table structure seems incredibly redundant to me.  You could get the exact same data by just adding a 'name' column to the page_data table and dropping the other two tables entirely.

Comment: Show actual table defs, sample data and sample output

Comment: That is not a good structure to use, are you able to change the database design, or do you have to use it? The 'fields'-comma separated string makes a join impossible and the page_data-table with one column per field makes your data contain a lot of NULL-values (as you can see in your example). This also does not scale well at all.

Comment: A better solution would be to have another table for "page has field" with columns (and primary keys) pageId and fieldId. The page_data could use pageId+fieldId as key, and only one column for content. The row "1, 1, 'MyPage'" then represent your title-data for page with id 1, "1, 3, 'This is the description'" would be your description.

Answer (score 1):

Under the relational model, domains should be simple; this is called "first normal form". In plainer terms, don't pack multiple values in a single column. Normalize the `pages` table by breaking up the `fields` column into another table. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE page_fields {
    page INT UNSIGNED,
    field INT UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY `page` REFERENCES `pages` (id),
    FOREIGN KEY `field` REFERENCES `data_fields` (id)
} Engine=InnoDB;
```

Then join the `pages`, `data_fields` and `page_data` tables using `page_fields`.

Alternatively, restructure the `page_data` table and do away with `data_fields`:

```
CREATE TABLE page_data {
    page INT UNSIGNED,
    name ENUM('title', 'subtitle', 'description', 'image', 'link', 'quote'),
    data VARCHAR(...),
    FOREIGN KEY page REFERENCES pages (id)
} Engine=InnoDB;
```

then join `pages` with `page_data`.

Answer (score 1):

nothing personal, but your design is redundand and poor. if you want, we can help you to reorganize you database structure.
I don't actually understand, why do you want to keep several tables? all the attributes you've counted belong to a single entity. there is no many-to-one, many-to-many relations, so it can be described in a single table, eg:

```
create table PAGES (
  id int not null,
  title varchar(256) null,
  subtitle  varchar(256) null,
  description varchar(1024) null,
  image blob null,
  link  varchar(256) null,
  quote varchar(256)
)
```

if the page does not have some attribute (title or drescription, etc) this field is just NULL, and you will keep it in mind when will process this information within php-script.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. How do I reply in more than one line in this forum?

Comment: So a better database structure would be?:

table pages:  

    id pagename 
    1 Home

table fields:

    id field type 
    1 title text 
    2 description textarea

table page_data:

    page_id field_id content
    1 1 Hello
    1 2 lorem ipsum dolor...

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not designed well. [Repeating groups within columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups_within_columns) are a PITA to work with. You should refactor your database design and then use [Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).